# Ubunto 19.10 can't install Controller Update?

Tags: firmware

Every time I restart my computer and open up "Ubuntu Software" I have a Controller update that says `ThinkPad P53/P73 Embeddd Controller Update 0.1.7 -> 0.1.08`. I click `update` and no errors appear but it seems to install quicker than would be possible (quite instantaneously) which makes me think that my machine isn't actually updating. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

from a terminal.